# Prove that if L is a recursive language, then its complement Ls is also recursive

Tags: computer-science, recursion, formal-languages, automata, turing-machines

Considering that a language $L$ is recursive iff there exist a Turing machine $T$ that accepts every string of the language $L$ and rejects all strings that don't match the alphabet of $L$.

In other words, if string $S$ is part of the alphabet of language $L$, then the turing machine $T$ will accept it and halts, otherwise the turing machine halts without ever reaching an accepting state.

I've already been working in this proof:

$L$ is a language accepted by a turing machine that halts on all inputs. We construct a turing machine Ts from $T$. turing machine $T$ given an input string $S$ enters into an accepting state then Ts rejects and halts for string $W$. Also, if the turing machine $T$ halts without accepting $W$, Ts enters into an accepting state. Ts accepts strings that are not accepted by $T$. Therefore, Ts recognizes the complement of $L$.

But I want to show the next "if language $L$ is accepted by Turing $T$ then it is rejected by $T_s$ and if it is accepted by Ts then it is rejected by T" And conclude that $L(T_s)=L_s$ Therefore $L_s$ is recursive.

Any ideas?

Comment: On any given input, the original Turing machine halts in an accepting or rejecting state. Just relabel all accepting states as rejecting and vice versa. The new machine is still guaranteed to halt and gives the opposite result of the original machine.

Comment: The alphabet is the set of input letters of the Turing machine, so I don'r know what you mean by "the alphabet of the language".